# Is it true that Johannes Kepler thought that the earth was hollow?

Tags: physics, 17th-century, kepler

I was researching a little about the hollow earth theory, I know that many Scientist's back up this theory, namely Euler and Edmond Halley.
I would like to know what was the theory that Johannes Kepler had about it and what is his idea of the structure of the earth in his book called Somnium, the problem is that the book was written in Latin, and it is a little difficult to understand for that I would like to appreciate to know the opinion of a expert in this area.
An also to know if is that true that Kepler in this particular book claimed that the earth is hollow.

Comment: What makes you think that it is true? I cannot find a shred of evidence that Kepler thought this. Somnium is basically a sci-fi novel, and you'll get no help there. It has been translated to English; you can buy a copy on Amazon. Until you have any actual reason to even suspect that Kepler made such a claim, I'd say your question is on shaky ground.

Comment: do you mean that Kepler just wanted to write a sci-fi novel? with that book, I would like to know in what level he thought that his writing was true, maybe he believed that this was a kind of vision. The other fact is that i would like to know if in this book he claimed that the earth was hollow. I would like to know the opinion  of a person that has read the book and has a very clear opinion of this.

Comment: Yes it's a blatant science fiction novel. Like 20th century sci-fi, it includes a combination of total fiction bordering on fantasy, possibly some speculative fiction, and of course, elements of what he understood about astronomy at the time. If you don't want to actually buy a copy and read the entire story, [here is a fragment](http://frostydrew.org/papers.dc/papers/paper-somnium/pss-fdo/) of the translation, and you might also read the [Wiki Plot Summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somnium_(novel)).

Comment: This novel is for some the first serious scientific treatise on lunar astronomy,  but is also referred to it as the first work of science fiction for some persons such as Sagan and Issac Asimov, but that fact doesn't not imply that he wrote it as a science fiction novel maybe he believed that some facts were really true, some scientists had also strange theories since their believes for instance Newton however the main question for me is what was the structure of the earth that Kepler postulated in this particular book.